# What is LLVM CodeGen optimization?

Tags: llvm

The ExecutionEngine class in LLVM library has a option to set the *CodeGen optimization level* (`CodeGenOpt::Level`). Do I understand it right that CodeGen optimizations are applied during machine code generation and they are not related to IR? If I want to optimize IR I need to do it with other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizations that happen in the JIT when CodeGenOpt is set are a) which instruction selector is chose (fast isel vs selection dag), and b) whether any optimizations are run during the MC level passes.

If you want optimization on the IR level you'll need to create your own PassManager and add the passes you want to run.